# Is fb graph user search api not working anymore?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=sharma&fields=name&type=user&access_token=

I was this URL along with access token and it was giving me user name list that i was using in my project. Only names are my requirement but when today i started to use it i am not getting any data nor any error.

Its only returning this

```
{
  "data": [
 ]
}
```

Recently a month ago it was working for me.
Can anyone tell me if they have the same issue or if something has changed?

Is there any other was of getting users name mainly first + last name from fb?

Comment: Please search before asking ... this topic has come up multiple times over the last few days already.

Comment: Plus, mentioned in the official places as well: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Comment: @CBroe i am sorry but i was not able to find that chanelog info. Is there any other method by which i can get user first + last names?

Comment: Have them login to your app, then you can read their details. (And if they are not users of your app, you have very little business getting that data in the first place.)

Comment: @CBroe no they dont login. Let me tell you what i want, For example, i need list of names that have "smith" as a surname. I was using fb graph search api for that. i dont need any personal data. i just need few names  for each surname..

Comment: there is no way to do that anymore. names ARE personal data.

Comment: Thing is that the same rule applies for public pages too. I am not sure i understand the reasoning behind this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found answer of my question which is Fb is no more giving user results for graph search api.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Search API
You can no longer use the /search endpoint with the following object types:

event

group

page

user

I dont know whether its a permanent revoke or temporary but it has something to do with Cambridge analytica data leak issue

https://www.google.co.in/search?biw=1360&bih=662&tbm=nws&ei=-iTXWrrkCYrxvgTTy5GgCw&q=cambridge+analytica+data+leak&oq=cambridge+analytica+data+leak

I hope it will help others to find out why their API is not working anymore.